# Form: Keep posted parameters with Sails JS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have file `views/user/index.ejs`

```
<form action="" method="POST>
  <label>Username: </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= req.param('username') %>" name="username">
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Content of `api/controllers/UserController.js`

```
module.exports = {
  index: function (req, res) {
    sails.log(req.param('username'));
    // Result: invest
  }
}
```

Although the log print `"invest"`, but the content of input is `"undefined"`. I think that the array of requested parameters had not been kept.

Can anyone help me solve it? I will donate 2 eggs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to pass variables to your view:

```
module.exports = {
  index: function (req, res) {
    return res.view("user/index", {username: req.param('username')});
  }
}
```

In your view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= username %>" name="username">
```